# Processing data from text file in R

Tags: r, text, startswith

So, I have been trying to turn a text file (each line is a chat log) into R to turn it into a data frame and further tidy the data.

I am using read.Lines so I can have each log as a single line. Because read.Lines reads them a single long char; I then convert them to strings (I need to parse the log).

I loaded a text file as data frame as per below.

```
rawchat <- readLines("disc-W-App-avec-loy.txt")
rawchat <- as.data.frame(rawchat, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(rawchat) <- "chat"
```

I am currently trying to identify any row (42000) that starts with the number 1. I can't seem to apply correctly the `startsWith()` function or the `dplyr` `starts_with()`, even `grepl` with regular expressions.

Could it be the format of the observations of the data frame (`chr`)?

Comment: Can you provide an example of just two records (one starting with 1 and one not)? It might help a lot I think. I can't think of a reason why `grepl` shouldn't work

Comment: Doesn't `startsWith(rawchat$chat, '1')` work?

Comment: The records examples are:

`<date> <time> - <username> : <message>`

But when its a paragraph:
`<date> <time> - <username> : <message>`
`<second line of message>`

Comment: Is the *row* (date) or *message* (in first line in case of a paragraph) starting with `1`?